# How to apply shadow to react native View without affecting inner view elements?

Tags: react-native, shadow

[image: Please click on image]

I would like to know how to apply shadow only to the main outer view. Here on applying shadow, it's getting applied to all the inner elements

Comment: Add your code... we can't advise anything without your code

Comment: Set a background color to the shadow element like white color.

Comment: I posted a similar problem here with some code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358597/react-native-apply-shadow-to-outside-of-view-and-do-not-apply-to-inner-views

Answer (score 40):

The trick to make the shadow props of parent don't inherit to children element, is to set a background color to the component on which you set the shadow. For example that would be:

```
<View 
  style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
  shadowOffset={{height: 10}}
  shadowColor='black'
  shadowOpacity={0.5}
>
  <Text>{title}</Text>
</View>
```

Unfortunately this only works with colored backgrounds – when setting a transparent background with RGBA or 'transparent' is doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot really answer based on a simple image, but from my previous experience, setting shadow offset to the required height and width should do the trick for the iOS.

Read more about it here: [Shadow Offset](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props#shadowoffset)

Here's a picture of what my card looks like with the following style used:

```
marginLeft: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: 'blue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowOffset: {width: 3, height: 3 },
    shadowOpacity: 1.0,
    borderRadius: 10,
```

My card View

[image]
Hope it works out well for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Display custom shadow color >= 28 or >= P for above Sdk level 28**

[image]

**Code**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  <View
    style={{
      shadowColor: 'purple',
      height: 150,
      width: '90%',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      //android specific
      elevation: 10,
      //ios specific
      shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 1 },
      shadowRadius: 3,
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    }}>
    <Text style={{ color: 'rgba(128,0,128,0.5)' }}>
      Welcome to React Native
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

In **android** we can adjust shadow by `elevation` property

In **iOS** we can adjust shadow by `shadowOffset, shadowRadius,shadowOpacity` property

Output android

[image]

Output iOS

[image]

Available library for further usage

[react-native-shadow-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drop-shadow)
[react-native-drop-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drop-shadow)

Answer (score -1):

Create a Shadow.js

```
export const Shadow = (elevation) => { // Receive elevation as a prop
  return {
    elevation,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0.5 * elevation },
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 0.8 * elevation,
  };
};
```

import Shadow.js to the page where you want to apply

```
import Shadow from './Shadow'  //path to Shadow.js

<View style={{Shadow(5)}}> // pass elevation as a prop to Shadow.js
</View>
```

if you want to use in styles

```
import Shadow from './Shadow'  //path to Shadow.js

<View style={styles.shadow}>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 shadow:{
    ...Shadow(5) //use spread operator
}
});
```