# React Native: Apply shadow to outside of View and do not apply to inner views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, shadow, box-shadow

This is what my page looks like

[image]

I am trying to get a shadow only where the red line is

[image]

I don't want shadow on the inner elements, especially not the text. I also want the shadow to appear below the View.

This is how I am styling my View

```
  myOuterView: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginTop: 10,

  },
```

---

Answers on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914868/how-to-apply-shadow-to-react-native-view-without-affecting-inner-view-elements) did not work or caused other problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below example which i created a Shadow box for both **ios** and **android**. Its  a little bit tricky when it comes to 'ios' and i have clearly shown that in the example below. i think this will help you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';

const screenHieght = Dimensions.get('window').height;
class ShadowBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        <View style={styles.innerView}>
          <View style={styles.outer}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>card </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.outer}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>card </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  innerView: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#fff' : null,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    shadowColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'green' : '#fff',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 3 : 0,
      height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 3 : 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 1 : 0.8,
    shadowRadius: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 40,
    elevation: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 4,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
  outer: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: '80%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
};

export default ShadowBox;
```

Change this according to your requirement. Feel free to ask me any doubts that you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Add background color to your stylesheet `myOuterView`.

```
myOuterView: {
    ...
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    ...
}
```