# Why is shadow in react native being applied to text?

Tags: react-native, shadow

I have following component:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.event} onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.eventDate}>Sent at : {event.sentAt}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.eventTextContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.eventText}>{event.text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

then in my styles:

```
event: {
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
        width: 5,
        height: 5,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.75,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
    ...Platform.select({
      android: {
        elevation: 5,
      },
    }),
eventTextContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    eventText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '700',
    }
```

The shadow is being applied to the text, which I dont want, only want it applied to the touchable opacity, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: In this case wrap the text into View and give it the style with shadow.

Comment: Can you add your `styles.eventTextContainer` and `styles.eventText` code ?

Comment: @Yasuooooooooo just did

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914868/how-to-apply-shadow-to-react-native-view-without-affecting-inner-view-elements), the key to avoid this problem is applying a background color to the container with the shadow styles, in your case is the ***event*** style.

```js
event: {
  shadowColor: "#000",
  shadowOffset: {
    width: 5,
    height: 5,
  },
  shadowOpacity: 0.75,
  shadowRadius: 3.84,
  ...Platform.select({
    android: {
    elevation: 5,
  },
  backgroundColor: "#FFF",
}),
```