# How to style parent component without affecting child component in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to style my parent component (Touchable Opacity - foodCard) with a box shadow which seems to be working but for some reason it is also adding box shadows to the child components? Is there any way I can add a box shadow to the parent without it adding shadows to the text/ image inside? Thanks

Please see image, only the foodCard itself should have a shadow and not the text/ image on the card. [image: IMAGE EXAMPLE]

```
  const renderFoods = () => {
return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data={menuItems}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.foodCard}
          onPress={() => {
            setMenuOption(true), setClickedItem(item);
          }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.flatlistImages}
            source={item.menu[0].photo}
          />
          <View style={styles.textContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {item.menu[0].calories} Calories
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>£{item.menu[0].price}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    />
  </View>
);
```

};

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
foodCard: {
marginBottom: 50,
shadowColor: '#000',
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 5,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.9,
shadowRadius: 2,
borderWidth: 1,
borderRadius: 20,
},
flatlistImages: {
width: '100%',
height: 250,
opacity: 1,
overflow: 'hidden',
borderTopStartRadius: 20,
borderTopEndRadius: 20,
},
textContainer: {
flexDirection: 'row',
justifyContent: 'space-between',
},
text: {
fontSize: 15,
margin: 10,
},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to move the

```
shadowColor: '#000',
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 5,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.9,
shadowRadius: 2,
```

from `foodCard` to the `flatlistImages` style

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately the children styles is still effected

Comment: @ubermo try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914868/how-to-apply-shadow-to-react-native-view-without-affecting-inner-view-elements), I think if you set `backgroundColor` to `white` will work